# Does jQuery overwrite event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-click-event

I've got a bunch divs which each contain a remove link attached with the click event below:

```
  var observeRemoveRoom = function
    $('.remove_room').click(function(){     
      $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    });
  }
```

Clicking it removes the 'active' class of the parent (the div). I call this `observeRemoveRoom` function on window load which works fine.

The thing is, I have another function which adds more of the same divs. Since the `a.remove_room` links contained within the new divs weren't around on `window.load` I need to call `observeRemoveRoom`.

Am I somehow duplicating the event handlers? Does jQuery overwrite them? If so should I unbind the handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you call `observeRemoveRoom` jQuery will add a new unique event handler function for a click event.

So yes, you need to `.unbind()` either *all* currently bound handlers by just calling `.unbind()` without arguments, or be specific and pass in a function reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be duplicating the event-handlers if you call `observeRemoveRoom` again, but it might not be noticeable since you are only calling the `removeClass` method which does nothing if the class is not found, which would be the case after the first listener is triggered.

Instead you can un-bind and re-bind the click event each time, like:

```
 var observeRemoveRoom = function(){
    var remove_class = function(){     
      $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    };
    $('.remove_room').off('click', remove_class).on('click', remove_class);
  }
```

But that said, it is recommended that you do this outside this function`, rather than binding and unbinding the event every time, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var remove_class = function(){     
      $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    };
    // If the element exists at dom ready, you can bind the event directly
    $('.remove_room').on("click", remove_class);
    // If the element is added in dynamically, you can [delegate][1] the event
    $('body').on("click", '.remove_room', remove_class);
    // Note: Although I've delegated the event to the body tag in this case
    // I recommend that you use the closest available parent instead
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events : [1]

Answer (score 1):

You can try a live query to keep them updated: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Comment: Huh, what's that plugin? Just use on() with a selector.

Comment: on() will only attach the events to the results of the query at the time you called it. Live queries add/remove the events when the DOM changes.

Comment: No, not when the DOM changes but when a jQuery method is called. Urghh. Better use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).